# spring batch multiple line to single object

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a csv file with customer, account and transaction information like below.

```
cust, abc, 123, 24-03-2017
acct, checking, c, 12, 25-03-2017
trans, 1233, c, 0.34
trans,2355, d, 0.45
cust, abc1, 1234, 24-03-2017
acct, checking, c, 12, 25-03-2017
trans, 1233, c, 0.34
cust, abc2, 12345, 24-03-2017
acct, checking, c, 12, 25-03-2017
trans, 1233, c, 0.34
trans, 1233, c, 0.34
trans, 1233, d, 0.34
```

i want each customer as one object like custTO it has acctTO in that i can have list of transactionTO...

tried using PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.

Please help me out..

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#multiLineRecords

Comment: that example we have one TO but i want cust as one TO in that acctTO as another member and in acctTO list of transactionTO as member..

Comment: i mean can i do it without customizing the itemreader itself... in some other way like by customizing the line mapper or some thing else but not reader

Comment: This kind of problem is usually solved using a custom ItemReader; this doesn't mean you have to extends FlatFileItemReader directly but use the delegation pattern instead

Comment: Is this is the way your suggesting..
public class MultiLineTradeItemReader implements ItemReader<Object>, ItemStream {
 private FlatFileItemReader<FieldSet> delegate; 
 @Override
 public Object read() throws Exception {
  Customer cust = null;
         for (FieldSet fs = null; (fs = this.delegate.read()) != null;) {
     if("cust".equalsIgnoreCase(fs.readString(0))){
      cust = new Customer ();
         cust.setName(fs.readString(1));
  ..
  }else if("acct".equalsIgnoreCase(fs.readString(0)))
  ..
  else if("trans".equalsIgnoreCase(fs.readString(0)))
  ..
  return cust;
 }
}

Comment: Above comment is totally useless for us. Try the code yourself and if you have other problems that blocks you update your question.